# Check if in ArrayList of size N, there are two numbers which their sum is N

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, heapsort

I have homework to do. 
I have to implement an algorithm, which has to check, if, into an ArrayList, of size N, there are at least two numbers, which added, their sum is N.
The complexity of the algorithm has to be Theta(n log n).
I already know that I can use the Merge.Sort, or, the Heap-Sort, then I have to subtract the size of the array list, with every element, of the array list.
The question is: Subtracting sequentially the complexity, will still be 
Theta(n log n)?!?
If not, how can I keep it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the array with MergeSort for O(n log n)
then for each record r_i in the array perform a lookup for record N - r_i using binary search which is O(log n)

You will have O(n log n) for mergeSort + O(n log n) for n binary search lookups --> O(n log n)

Comment: how does this work if there are 3 numbers in the list that add up to N? I think the question itself might not be solvable in O(nlog n) in its current form. (wondering)

Comment: @Vamsidhar Reddy Gaddam But who wants 3 numbers? I believe that author means: pair with need sum definitely exists.

Comment: into an ArrayList, of size N, there are "at least" two numbers, which added, their sum is N

Comment: copied from the question ^

Comment: This means - there is at least one pair (I agree that formulation is not exact)

Comment: that is why (wondering) - the other way seems a lot more fun though :P

Comment: @MBo is right. Sorry but i'm not english, nor from a country where english is spoken :P

Answer (score 1):

sort the array with any sort algorithm, preferably one with an acceptable order, like mergeSort which is (O(nlogn));

then start to check the first and last element of the array and keep their indexes, namely 'start' and 'end.
while the last element is bigger than your desired value, reduce the index by one, then compare that sum of the 'start' and 'end' with your desired value,

if its bigger than your desired value, you will not find any two values that satisfy your condition,

if its equal to your desired value, report the 'start' and 'end' elements

if its less than your desired value increment the 'start' index 
and do the comparison again,

repeat until the two indexes meet each other.

finally the complexity will be : O(n) + O(nlogn) which is equal to O(nlogn)